# Ghostscript pdf to jpeg with specific resolution and dimensions

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I have a pdf file containing plots of 7inx7in.  I need to create jpegs of these plots at 3inx3in and at a resolution of 400dpi for publication.  I've tried many things, but I'm lost.  So far I have:

gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r400 -g1200x1200 -sOutputFile=test%03d.jpg ./temp.pdf

According to the jpeg image properties, the resulting jpeg is the right resolution and dimensions, but it only contains the left hand corner of my plot.  If I replace the above with g=2800x2800, I get the plot fills the entire jpeg perfectly, but this is effectively making it the original 7inx7in dimensions instead of the 3inx3in I want.  I've tried various combinations of -dPDFFitPage, -dFIXEDMEDIA, but I can't get it right.

Any help would be appreciated,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Its not really going to be possible to help without having a specimen file to look at and experiment with. However You should set both -dFIXEDMEDIA and -dPDFFitPage.

Knowing the version of Ghostscript you are using would also be helpful, you may be using a version which doesn't have some features.